# How does Chrome load `vue.min.js` from ServiceWorker

Tags: service-worker

when visit the `https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js`, i find it's loaded from ServiceWorker, how it works?
[Screenshot of Chrome DevTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvm6T.png)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking (there's a "Why" in the subject, and a "How" in the question). Do you want to know "Why does Chrome load vue.min.js from ServiceWorker?" or "How does Chrome load vue.min.js from ServiceWorker?"?

Comment: Thank you, i had modifed the question

Answer (score 0):

A service worker is a piece of JavaScript code that your browser runs in the background. Service workers are given some special privileges over normal JavaScript code that runs in a browser, with a commonly used priveledge being their ability to intercept `fetch` events.

A fetch event is activated anytime the client requests a file. Many service workers will download all requested files into a cache. The second time the same file is requested, the service worker will step in and return the cached file without sending any http request.

In this particular case, a service worker is storing the contents of the vue file into a cache the first time it is downloaded, removing the need for an expensive network request on future page loads.